# How can I go out from a sub when another sub that is inside this sub outputs a Msgbox?

Tags: vba, excel

Inside a sub ("Sensitivities") I am calling another sub ("MVE_NIM_Subs.MVE_Main"), if this sub outputs a MsgBox I want to end the sub and to go to the "Jump" defined, instead of continuing executing the sub. ¿How can I do it?

Thanks

```
Public Sub Sensitivities() 
Application.Run "MVE_NIM_Subs.MVE_Main" 
........ 
Jump: 
End Sub
```

Comment: How many subs are using `MVE_NIM_Subs.MVE_Main`?  If this is the only call to it, why not include it in `Public Sub Sensitivities()`?  If more than one caller, could you test if the MsgBox will be displayed before it is and exit `MVE_NIM_Subs.MVE_Main`?

Comment: Let me guess, its a financial model for a bank and Now its time for stress test :). Too many consultants in and out and right now you are stuck with someone else's code. Both MacroMan and Michal have valid approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trap your Msgbox with a public boolean variable. In the sub `MVE_NIM_Subs.MVE_Main` modify your code to set a public boolean variable to be true if the msgbox appears.

After this sub ends, execution will go back to executing code inside sub `Sensitivities`. Then just check the value of the public boolean variable. If it's true, then go to Jump.

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public DidMsg As Boolean

Sub Sensitivities()

DidMsg = False
Application.Run "MVE_NIM_Subs.MVE_Main"

If DidMsg = True Then GoTo Jump
'rest of your code
'
'
'
'


Jump:
'rest of your code after point Jump
'
'
'
'
End Sub

Sub MVE_Main()

'your code whatever it is
'right after using the msgbox type:
DidMsg = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

MsgBox is a modal element, so code execution is paused until the user deals with it. This leaves you with two options:

1. Don't display a MsgBox (if you only want to stop code when this happens I'm not sure what the point of it is anyway?)
2. Create a non-modal userform to emulate a MsgBox instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to options in my opinion:

1. Make `MVE_NIM_Subs.MVE_Main` a function that returns `Bool`. When you display message box in `MVE_NIM_Subs.MVE_Main` set return value to `True`. Then in calling sub you can write:

   If returnValue Then GoTo Jump
2. Keep `MVE_NIM_Subs.MVE_Main` as sub and declare some global `Bool` variable, that can be used within two subs. In outer sub set it to `False` before calling `MVE_NIM_Subs.MVE_Main` and in `MVE_NIM_Subs.MVE_Main` set it to `True` whenever you show the message box. Then you can use it in outer sub to decide whether to jump or not, like in first option :)