# Verification before executing

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a useform with a button that allows you to select the folder you were going to work with (extract folder) and other button to perform other tasks, I would like to know how so that whenever I click on a button to execute a task it first checks if the button "extract folder" was selected otherwise do it first before executing the task.
Here is the code for the extraction folder.
Thank you for your help

```
Private Sub Repertoire_Click()
Dim folder As Office.filedialog
Set folder = Application.filedialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'Fênetre contextuelle pour le choix du dossier
With folder
.Title = "Selectionner le dossier contenant les extractions"
.AllowMultiSelect = False  '
 If .Show = -1 Then 
 ExtractionFolder = .SelectedItems(1)

End If
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Where id the extract folder button in all this and what type of button is it?

Comment: You could disable "Task" button on form load and enable it after "extract folder" procedure ends without errors. This way user won't be able to do any "tasks" unless he/she select folder.

Comment: Another option would be using a Public Variable (boolean). Make it true if the user clicks on this button. And rest of subs, if that variable is false, then warn user and exit sub. You can check an example on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51497134/9199828 but to be honest, I think that @Sphinx suggestion is more profesional and beautiful

Comment: i did something that's working fine for me `If extractionfolder <> "" Then MY CODE else: Msgbox (" Pick Folder") exit sub end if`